# Enqueue List method

Tags: java, list, arraylist, queue

Is there a way to enqueue this method faster? I'm trying to add performance test to this method and wondering if there is alternative for this.

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

  public class ImmutableQueueImpl<E> implements ImmutableQueue<E> {
      private     List<E> queue;
      public ImmutableQueueImpl() { 
        queue = new ArrayList<E>();
      }

      private ImmutableQueueImpl(List<E> queue) {
        this.queue = queue; }

      @Override
      public ImmutableQueue<E> enqueue(E e) {
        if (e == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        List<E> clone = new ArrayList<E>(queue); clone.add(e);
        return new ImmutableQueueImpl<E>(clone);
      }

      @Override
      public ImmutableQueue<E> dequeue() {
         if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
         }
         List<E> clone = new ArrayList<E>(queue); 
         clone.remove(0);
         return new ImmutableQueueImpl<E>(clone);
      }

      @Override 
      public E peek() {
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return queue.get(0); 
      }

     @Override 
     public int size() {
      return queue.size();
     }
    }
```

**EDIT**
   I have added the full code for reference. Hope that helps

Comment: What is `ImmutableQueueImpl`?

Comment: A Queue class representing an immutable first-in-first-out (FIFO) queue of objects.

Comment: Yes, I know what a queue is. But how are we meant to know whether there's a faster alternative to what you've shown if you don't tell us exactly what the `ImmutableQueueImpl` class is? For example, does it create *another* copy? Can you change its code?

Comment: Presumably you can implement this in constant rather that linear time then by simply tagging the current queue behind the new element and returning that?

Comment: U cannot change the state of the queue after we create it.    
Returns the queue that removes the object at the head of this queue without modifying this queue. 
e.g.
When this queue represents the queue (7, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1) , this method returns a new queue (1, 3, 3, 5, 1)
and this object still represents the queue (7, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1) .

Comment: @bmorris591 Is it possible to explain a bit more?

Comment: For that I would need to see the q. But I presume it is node based? With a head? Create a method internal to the q called `add` and create a private constructor that takes a new node and a q and constructs a new q with the node as the head.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get O(1) for enqueue/dequeue operations in immutable queue using 2 immutable lists internally.

Here is code borrowed from [Scala book](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html):

```
class Queue[T](
  private val leading: List[T],
  private val trailing: List[T]
) {
  private def mirror =
    if (leading.isEmpty) new Queue(trailing.reverse, Nil)
    else this

  def head = mirror.leading.head

  def tail = {
    val q = mirror
    new Queue(q.leading.tail, q.trailing)
  }

  def append(x: T) = new Queue(leading, x :: trailing)
}
```